# how to create a calculated column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, functions, database-projects

I want to create a table, this table's name is "Prod", in his table, I have the:
**ID**, **name**, **Buying_price** and **selling_price**
when the user inserts the data, I want him to enter "name, and buying_price" and I'd like the column of **selling_price** to be calculated depending on the user's input by this method (buying_price + 20% Buying_price)

I don't know how to do this, I thought that a function/procedure could help but I have no idea how to do it, since I am new to database and SQL I would so much appreciate any help

Comment: Oracle SQL and MySQL are two different database systems. Which one are you using?

Comment: Where does the "20%" come from? I mean, I realise it's "user's input", but how would the database know what it is?

Comment: @J.D. Hello sir, i am using sql oracle

Comment: @mustaccio Hello, I will give you an example to make it clear. Let's say the user gave us the buying price: 95$, so I need to calculate the selling price like this : 
95 + ((20*95)/100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1 (buying_price number, 
     selling_price number generated always as (buying_price * 1.2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 (buying_price) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

BUYING_PRICE SELLING_PRICE
------------ -------------
         100           120
```

Comment: thank you so much